# jQuery fadeOut CSS3 replacement

Tags: jquery, ipad, css, fadeout

I know its been posted before, but what I deem to be a suitable answer was not provided, so I'll ask again as I want to use the same code as need it to be ipad compatible.

Is there a way that the jQuery function .fadeOut can be re-written to use CSS3? or even a jquery function like.

```
.css3fadeout()
```

that then runs a similar sequence to

```
$(this).addClass('CLASS WITH FADE OUT ANIMATION');
$(this).delay(2000).hide();
```

thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why weren't the answers to the duplicate question(s) suitable?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WPTrw/?

Comment: @Colin required to many code changes that effected how the app worked, and thanks j08691 ill try that

Answer (score 0):

You could write a new function/plugin using this reference http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.

Or you could overwrite the function using this reference: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-Ask-Ben-Overriding-Core-jQuery-Methods.htm

Comment: I would set the style rather than using a class though. (http://api.jquery.com/css/)